# Will the OS ever kill a started service and call `Service.onDestroy`?

Tags: android, android-service

I am running a few tasks using a thread pool in a started foreground service. And, specifically, the service never calls `stopSelf()` until the tasks are finished. I am wondering if it is necessary to interrupt/shutdown the thread pool in the `onDestroy()` method. Will the OS ever forcefully destroy the service and call `onDestroy()`? I know the OS can "kill" the service by killing the process but does it ever "kill" the service by simply destroying it.

Extra details: the service is not exported so external code cannot call `Context.stopService()` and none of my own code calls `Context.stopService()`, only `Service.stopSelf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, before Android terminates the process due to low memory conditions, it is supposed to call `onDestroy()` on all running components, assuming that there is adequate time to do so. In practice, I haven't tested this scenario in ages.

Also, older versions of Android used to allow users to stop services through a Settings screen, and there is nothing stopping device manufacturers from offering a similar capability today.

I generally try to clean things up in `onDestroy()`, just to be safe.

Comment: Update: I was going through the developer options and found "Running Services". This allows the user to "Stop" a running service without destroying the process. While it is not typical for users to use developer options, there is no way for me to prevent it. And your comment about stopping services through Settings is still correct in Android 12L, at least in AOSP.